# Is there a way to run an HTML file with default browser and a parameter?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, filesystems, internet-explorer, html

I have an HMTL file that I would like to be opened with the user's default browser, followed by a parameter. For example, if your default browser was Google Chrome, it would open as:

```
C:/Users/[User]/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Applications/chrome.exe -[parameter]
```

This probably isn't how this should be handled, and I know this isn't secure or ideal. But I would like to know how (if you even can at all) you could make this happen.

Thanks.

Comment: What would this parameter be for?  The web page, or the browser?

Comment: yeah that is how it works normally!! chrome %1 where %1 is the parameter which is the html file

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 the parameter would be for the browser. The exact parameter I need is --allow-file-access-from-files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Windows System use:

**cmd /c start http://superuser.com**

---

**What this command does is:**

**cmd** Opens the command line window.
**/c** is a parameter for the command line window. It tells the command line window to close itself after finishing.

This command line window shall run the command start.

**start** opens a new command prompt, to run a command.
    The command that start shall run is in this case: http://superuser.com

**start http://superuser.com** means, open the http://superuser.com with the default program assigned to it.

Which program is assigned can be looked up in the command line window with: **ftype**, and **assoc**
    In case of the http protocoll you can use ftype and search for the entry starting with http= to see which program is assigned to it.
    If nothing is assigned in ftype or assoc, then explorer.exe is called with the parameter of start.

Comment: I know this is dumb, but some people might not understand what this does. Can you explain it, even just a little?

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need, but when I open the file (run the shortcut) it doesn't seem that the parameters are applied. Is there another way to apply the parameter to the end of this other than:

`cmd /c start http://superuser.com -[param]` ?